# Install flutter in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: android, flutter, dart, ubuntu-18.04

I installed the flutter and android studio  with snap:

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

and

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk
sudo snap install android-studio --classic
```

When I run the flutter doctor I get the following message:

```
rahunn3@acer-ubuntu:~$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    ✗ android-studio-dir = /home/rahunn3/snap/android-studio
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

When I run the flutter doctor -v the following message is displayed for Android studio block:

```
[!] Android Studio
• Android Studio at /home/rahunn3/snap/android-studio
✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
✗ android-studio-dir = /home/rahunn3/snap/android-studio
✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
• Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
• Consider removing your android-studio-dir setting by running:
  flutter config --android-studio-dir=
```

I have installed the flutter and dart plugin for the Android Studio IDE.

How do I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a weird behavior, in the error message it says it can't find the bundled java version.
Have you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Open Android studio & download flutter plugins from Sdk manager->plugins